# Why does the distribution of the error term in a regression model matter?

Tags: statistics, regression

When we want to build a regression model $Y = f(X)+\epsilon$, why does the distribution of $\epsilon$ matter at all? Why don't we go ahead and find the best $f(X)$ that optimizes a performance measure (for example, minimizes the MSE)? What are the implications of assuming that $\epsilon$ has a normal, Poisson (when it is a count model), or any other distribution?

Comment: Distributional assumptions guarantee certain good properties. How else would you guarantee that the MSE is well defined in the population? If not, minimizing MSE is meaningless. Parametric distributional assumptions let you derive finite sample distributions of your estimator for inference. They also let you answer some optimality questions like “what is the best possible estimator given this class of distributions”?

Comment: You estimate the coefficient based on a sample. And the sample is random. So the estimated regression model has a random part.